# How do I write to a file with boost.log?

Tags: c++, boost

I couldn't find much helpful ressources on the web. They said i had to use boost::log::add_file_log.
But Visual Studio as well as the compiler could find this function in the boost library.
I also made sure to include all boost/log header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon *they* were idly chatting about `boost-log v2`, which is not in boost yet to the best of my knowledge.

You need to add a [sink back-end](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html). Here’s an example:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main() {

    using namespace boost::log;

    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_file_backend> sink_t;

    boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink(
        new sink_t(boost::make_shared<sinks::text_file_backend>(
            keywords::file_name="my.log")));
    core::get()->add_sink(sink);

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "hello";
}
```

[***See it live***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1be57eb42263a9fb)